# Phaser animation doesn't work on touch screen devices. (works fine on desktop)

Tags: javascript, android, animation, phaser-framework

I have these animations in my phaser.js game:

```
this.anims.create({
        key: 'catchingUp',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('android', { start: 0, end: 4}),
        frameRate: this.frameSpeed * 6,
        repeat: 0
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'catchingDown',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('android', { start: 5, end: 9}),
        frameRate: this.frameSpeed * 6,
        repeat: 0
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'topTop',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames('androidTopTop', { start: 0, end: 9}),
        frameRate: this.frameSpeed * 6,
        repeat: 0
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'downUp',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('androidUpDown', { start: 0, end: 4}),
        frameRate: this.frameSpeed * 6,
        repeat: 0
    });
```

Only the animation with key `downUp` works fine across all devices, it's the only one where the sprite just moves it's arm and doesn't go from one side to the other. Animations with keys `catchingUp` and `catchingDown` cause a black rectangle appear on the screen instead of my sprite; on phones and tablets, despite working fine on laptop.
I thought the problem was animations themselves, because character skips several frames, so I've made another animation `topTop`, same problem. Then i thought to put all the animations in one spritesheet , but that only caused **all** of them to be a black triangle, including 'downUp' animation which on it's own worked fine.

I've seen someone else asking similar question here and they were advised to use `this.anims.generateFrameNames` instead of `this.anims.generateFrameNumbers`, so i did that. Same, worked fine on desktop, black triangle everywhere else.

Before, when I used non animated images, instead of animations, it worked fine across all devices.

The game in it's current state can be found at https://chylinski82.github.io/androidCoop/ and all the code on https://github.com/chylinski82/androidCoop, the animations are in Level.js and they're called from basketUpRight.js, basketUpLeft.js, basketDownRight.js, basketDownLeft.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `width` of your sprite. If you split your sprite into multiple line lets say 4 line, the dimensions would be *`2400 x 1000`* instead of *`9000 x 250`* and this works on android(btw width of 4500, also doesn't work).
*(I could not test it on iphoneOs, but I asume this is the same issue)*

I couldn't findout *(yet)*, what the exact `width` limit is, but I know that there is a some problems width sprites, that have a large `width`.

**Update:** I just tested it on Android 12, `width` and `height` it is both limited for sprite animations at `4096px`, just tested it.

Comment: Brilliant! It's working now! Thanks a million you saved me loads of time, i wasn't going to give up on this one. It did cross my mind, but i didn't know that you could split your sprite sheet like that in rows and that phaser would still know how to put it together.

Comment: @chylinski yes phaser has some cool _(like the spritesheet spliting)_, but also some not so cool undocumented stuff like the `4092px` limit. In anycase great to here that it works.

Comment: even if it was documented, i wouldn't be able to read it, i can read documentations like MDN and make some sense out of them, but I'm clueless with phaser documentation, that's one of the reasons why i end up asking mainly phaser related questions, not much info out there.